# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_mysql'?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Environment:

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)

Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

Python 3.7.5

Flask 1.1.2

Werkzeug 1.0.1

We deployed a flask application on our VPS ubuntu. When we test with a browser, I get an error 500. When I checked gunicorn.log :  cat /var/log/gunicorn.log

```
[2021-04-08 18:37:21,413] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1020, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: 140258434049856

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co/dashboard.domain.co/Domain_dashboard/dashboard/routes.py", line 282, in home
    if form.validate_on_submit():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 100, in validate_on_submit
    return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 318, in validate
    return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 150, in validate
    if not field.validate(self, extra):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 226, in validate
    stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 246, in _run_validation_chain
    validator(form, self)
  File "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co/dashboard.domain.co/Domain_dashboard/dashboard/forms.py", line 53, in validate_email
    user = User.query.filter_by(user_email=email.data).first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 514, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1022, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3309, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 138, in __init__
    bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 943, in engine
    return self.get_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 962, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 556, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = self._sa.create_engine(sa_url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 972, in create_engine
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 520, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_mysql'
```

So I searched on google and here. I saw so many similar questions. So I tried the recommendation. pip install this, pip install that, but I always come back to same issue :
Internal Server Error 500
and
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_mysql'

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

**MORE INFO:**

pip freeze:

```
apparmor==2.12
asn1crypto==0.24.0
blinker==1.4
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
cheroot==8.4.5
CherryPy==18.6.0
click==7.1.2
cloud-init==20.3
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
configparser==5.0.2
cryptography==2.1.4
db-mysql==0.1.2
distro-info===0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.6
iotop==0.6
isc==2.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jaraco.classes==3.1.0
jaraco.collections==3.0.0
jaraco.functools==3.0.1
jaraco.text==3.2.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jsonpatch==1.16
jsonpointer==1.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
language-selector==0.1
LibAppArmor==2.12
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
more-itertools==8.5.0
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.23
mysql-connector-python-rf==2.2.2
mysqlclient==1.3.10
netifaces==0.10.4
oauthlib==2.0.6
ply==3.11
portend==2.6
protobuf==3.15.7
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygobject==3.26.1
PyJWT==1.5.3
PyMySQL==0.10.1
pyserial==3.4
python-apt==1.6.5+ubuntu0.3
pytz==2020.1
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.4
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23
ssh-import-id==5.7
tempora==4.0.0
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3
zc.lockfile==2.0
```

I added the environment variable
export $PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/

I added in the . bashrc file.

I restarted apache2 and the issue is still there. It didn't fix anything?

**EDIT: I added the list of packages from command "apt list --installed":**
As there are too many packages, I uploaded the list on [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U92cNp2759K71RxTxBvCH3SNOLg0ykxtivanghDQDGI/edit?usp=sharing).

I think the main interesting ones are:

```
default-libmysqlclient-dev/bionic   now 1.0.4   
libdbd-mysql-perl/bionic    now 4.046-1 
libmysqlclient-dev/bionic-updates   bionic-security now 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
libmysqlclient20/bionic-updates bionic-security now 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
mysql-common/bionic bionic  now 5.8+1.0.4
python-mysql.connector/bionic   bionic  now 2.1.6-1
python-mysqldb/bionic   now 1.3.10-1build1  
python3-mysql.connector/bionic  bionic  now 2.1.6-1
python3-mysqldb/bionic  now 1.3.10-1build1
```

Knowing I have Python 3.7.5, the question are now :

WHich packages I must uninstall?

Which version I must reinstall in order to make work python MySQL on my ubuntu server?
What are the commands?

Comment: Do you have a file named _mysql (other than that provided by the package itself)

Comment: @TheTahaan dorry, i have no idea

Comment: Could you try running your application under virtualenv with just the required libs used in your application? Once you successfully able to run the applications using virtualenv, we can do a diff between the virtualenv libs vs Ubuntu server libs and get things resolved.